# Python prints an incomplete list of a summation of two lists

Tags: python, list, for-loop, return

I'm trying to calculate (and print) the summation of two lists, given in the code below

```
def a(list1, list2):
    rv = []
    for i in range(len(list1)):
        rv.append(list1[i] + list2[i])
        return rv
list1 = [1, 2]
list2 = [3, 4]
d = a(list1, list2)
print('rv =', d)
```

but the above print function only prints
`rv = [4]` which is only the zeroth entry of `rv`, I was expecting it to print `rv = [4, 6]`
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`return rv` must be de-indented out of the for loop, otherwise it will exit the function in the first iteration:

```py
def a(list1, list2):
    rv = []
    for i in range(len(list1)):
        rv.append(list1[i] + list2[i])
    return rv
```

---

<sub>P.S. - your code can be simplified using `zip` and a list comprehension:</sub>

```py
def a(list1, list2):
    return [a + b for a, b in zip(list1, list2)]
```

Comment: Just as a quick question, does it matter where exactly I call the function I defined? i.e., if i call {d = a(list1, list2)) like I did at the bottom, or if I call it just after I define the function {a}, does it matter?

Comment: @AliAlKayyali You can't call a function before its definition. You must call it below the `def`